# Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ . If $f$ Is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ is f differentiable at $a$ and $b$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Just started a real analysis course and encountered this problem

> Let $ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $. If $f$ is continuous on $ [a,b] $ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ is f differentiable at $a$ and $b$ ?

I feel like the answer is yes, but I have no idea on a way to start with the proof...

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ over the interval $[-1,1]$.
Does this function satisfy all the assumptions? Is $f$ differentiable at the extreme points $x=1$ and $x=-1$?

Comment: thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be, consider a function that is the upper half of the circle defined as:

$$\left(x - \frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2+y^2=\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2$$

$y(x)$ is continuous at $[a, b]$ and differentiable at $(a, b)$, but the differentiates do not exist at points $a$ and $b$.

Comment: thank you so much for your counterexample.

Comment: @TUFFCLUBBOY you can show gratitude by upvoting;)